# MySQL query to select join from 5 tables

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

I have 5 tables:

```
tag: {tagID,tagDetails}
user: {userID,userDetails,u_status=[active or banned]}
subscribe: {tagID,userID}
item: {itemID, itemDetails,i_status=[active or banned]}
item_tag: {tagID,itemID}
```

I want to select these data:

```
result: {tagID, tagDetails, num_subscribers, num_items}
```

For each tagID, num_subscribers is the number of users under the table user whose u_status is 'active' and whose userID and the said tagID exists in the table subscribe

For each tagID, num_items is the number of users under the table item whose i_status is 'active' and whose itemID and the said tagID exists in the table item_tag

Also, I want all the tagID to appears in the result. If there are no users subscribing or items associated with that tagID, the record will be

```
{tagID,tagDetails,0,0}
```

What is the best (as 'human readable' as possible) one nested query that produce this result?

Comment: It seams like a straightforward `JOIN` between these five tables, why didn't you try to write it yourself? after that you can ask if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```
        SELECT T.tagID, T.tagDetails, count(distinct U.u_status), count(distinct I.i_status)
        FROM tag T
             JOIN subscribe S ON T.tagID = S.tagID
             JOIN user U ON S.userID = U.userID
             JOIN item_tag IT ON T.tagID = IT.tagID
             JOIN item I ON IT.itemID = I.itemID
        WHERE U.u_status = 'active' and I.i_status = 'active'
        GROUP BY T.tagID

        UNION

        (SELECT tagID, tagDetails, 0, 0
        FROM tag
        EXCEPT
        SELECT T.tagID, T.tagDetails, 0, 0
        FROM tag T
             JOIN subscribe S ON T.tagID = S.tagID
             JOIN user U ON S.userID = U.userID
             JOIN item_tag IT ON T.tagID = IT.tagID
             JOIN item I ON IT.itemID = I.itemID
        WHERE U.u_status = 'active' and I.i_status = 'active'
        GROUP BY T.tagID)
```

You might have to fiddle with the brackets and aliasing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to mention that I want all the tagID to appears in the result. If there are no users subscribing or items associated with that tagID, the record will be {tagID,tagDetails,0,0}

Comment: This will have count(U.u_status) equals to count(I.i_status), while they are not necessarily so. There may be a case:

One tag has one subscriber and two items under that tag.
tagID: 1
(tagID,userID): (1,1)
(tagID,itemID): (1,1), (1,2)

The table will be:
(tagID,userID,itemID): (1,1,1), (1,1,2)
(tagID,num_subs,num_items): (1,2,2)

I want the (tagID,num_subs,num_items) to be (1,1,2)

Comment: yeap, oh and also a bit modification, add GROUP BY T.tagID before UNION. Thanks, it's working nicely now.

Comment: Then surely you would need a group by tagID at the end as well? I'll edit to reflect these changes, if you disagree with the group by at the end then please edit it out.